# Swift - Disable Links in WebView

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, swift

I m currently looking for a way to disable Links in my WebView, this is my WebView

```
import UIKit

class ViewController_webView_news: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var WebViewNews: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var TBB_news: UITabBarItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var TBB_news_img = UIImage(named: "TabbarNews.png") as  UIImage
        TBB_news.selectedImage = TBB_news_img
        var newsurl = "http://google.com"
        let newsViewUrl = NSURL(string: newsurl)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: newsViewUrl)
        WebViewNews.loadRequest(request)




    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        }
    @IBAction func BThome(sender: AnyObject) {

        var newsurl = "http://google.com"
        let newsViewUrl = NSURL(string: newsurl)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: newsViewUrl)
        WebViewNews.loadRequest(request)
    }
    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ : UIWebView){activity.startAnimating()
    }
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ : UIWebView){activity.stopAnimating()}
```

Is there a way to use "UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked" for this?
Currently i m using

```
let result = WebViewNews.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("window.location.href = \"http://google.de\";")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use UIWebViewDelegate method and set it return to NO always. this way it will never load any other url. This is objective c code you need change it to swift.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return NO;
}
```

For swift [read here](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/PRERELEASE/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:)

Swift:

```
func webView(WebViewNews: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
return false;
}
```

Comment: But this is Objective C only or didn't i see this in swift?

Comment: added this after my "WebViewNews.loadRequest(request)" but it still let me click links

Comment: @FabianBoulegue, is shouldStartLoadWithRequest getting called when your click on any link? if not the it might be possible that you have not set delegate for UIWebView.

Comment: Your right its not called but i have set 

class ViewController_webView_news: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate

As well the WebView Delegates to the MainView see here http://i.epvpimg.com/Uc5ib.png

Comment: see below it get fried but at first loading so nothing appeals

Comment: But what should i add to let the links stop working ... i don't get it :( @Deepak

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61969/discussion-between-deepak-and-fabian-boulegue).