# How to Disable all the Links from webView once it is loaded?

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I am making simple web based application where I want to disable all the links when the page is loaded fully into the webView and for that I also tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056670/swift-disable-links-in-webview). But when I try this my `UIActivityIndicatorView` is stopped displaying.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var Activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Activity.hidden = true
    var myString = "https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_456"
    let myURL = NSURL(string: myString)
    let myReq = NSURLRequest(URL: myURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(myReq)
    webView.delegate = self

}
func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView){

    var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
    var activityBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: activityIndicator)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = activityBarButtonItem
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView){

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me how can I achieve that?

Thanks In advance!

Answer (score 0):

What about displaying a transparent view over it?

EDIT

Try adding a new gesture recognizer to it and tell it to do nothing for taps?

```
let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("handleTouch:"))
recognizer.delegate = self
webView.addGestureRecognizer(newTap)

func handleTouch(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {}
```

Theres a great tut on gestures in swift here [Swifty_Gestures](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial)

Comment: It will not scroll if I do that.

Comment: Well you would have to add gesture recognition to the transparent view but the point is that you would control exactly what happens. So scrolling would be possible if you handle it ie pass the command over to the underlying web view and scroll.

Comment: what should I put into this function so that user can not click on any link?